# Can't play sound using SoundPlayer in Visual Studio 2010 c#

Tags: c#, audio

I'm trying to play a sound but I just don't hear anything coming from speakers. All the code goes trough without any errors. My code:

```
using (SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer("c:\\scifi.wav"))
{
     player.PlaySync();
}
```

The sound is actualy there and exists, also if I try to play it with VLC or some other player it works.

I tried playing system sound like that

```
System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

and it works.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: I suppose you have looked onto this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should work:

```
System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
player.SoundLocation = "c:\\scifi.wav";
player.Play();
```

Some other possibilities:

Are you sure that scifi.wav is actually a .wav file and not a .mp3?

Comment: Great point at should, but if it would be so easy I would already got it working :D

Comment: Did you try without the `using clause`?

Comment: Yes, I did, and file is actualy a wav file because if it would be mpr it wouldn't load at all. And i also can see .wav...

Comment: Could you try another .wav file, just for the heck of it? And try following path: `"C:\scifi.wav"`

Comment: Ok, thanks for some reason it wont play that file i wanted but plays another waw. So i'm not totaly retarded and something is wrong with wav file. Thanks!!!

Comment: Nice you got it working! It is always hard to find the exact problem, did you try opening scifi.wav with windows media player, it sometimes gives you a helpful exception about what the real cause is.

Comment: Well WMP plays it without any problem. Totaly weird.

Comment: Yes, could have something to do with the bitrate, could you check the difference between them and post them?